# Why is my array.find and array.filter returning empty

Tags: arrays, typescript, string, angular13

I have an Array that looks like this

```
resultList: any[];
this.resultList = [
    {
        "id": "14e6f101-f8e8-4914-930f-cbba7a9c5328",
        "value": "Dream Inc."
    },
    {
        "id": "9a16c1c0-68f3-498a-b968-61849ccc2a21",
        "value": "Dressing, Inc.  ABC LOREBOX SERVICES"
    },
    {
        "id": "919b3cdb-c5fb-40c8-b88f-6c7f44f8446f",
        "value": "Dresson-Brand Company"
    }
]
```

I am having a hard time trying to retrieve the second item (index 1) by using the value. I can get the other two items by value but the second item returns undefined

code I am using

```
search(value: any) {
 //value coming in
 //Dressing, Inc. ABC LOREBOX SERVICES
 console.log('*** value to search ***', value);
 var foundObj = this.resultList.find(p => p.value == value);
 console.log('*** foundObj ***', foundObj);
}
```

foundObj comes back empty and same results when I do a filter. Any idea's what is wrong with that string that it can't be found? It seems I can get any other string (this is a dynamic array) but this one.

Comment: did you check if the value of resultList is as expected and please verify that your search does not have any newline characters or space, which you may miss in a console log.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Michael. In my code I consoled what the resultList was and the string in the value is the same string commented out for value coming in. I will double check though.

Comment: @MichaelR.  you led me to the right spot. What was happening is in the <option> of my component I wasn't specifying a value attribute (I was using data-value) which from what I found out removes spaces, etc. I added that and it is picking it up. If you want, add that as the answer and I'll mark as such. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from the dataList I was using. In the  element I was missing the 'value' attribute. Once I added that the spaces were no longer removed and my filtering was able to pick it up.